# Can't find moveit_benchmark_statistics.py

Tags: moveit, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to create a pdf of my benchmark.log-file by using following command:

```
faps@faps-Aspire-5740D:~/Desktop$ rosrun moveit_ros_benchmarks moveit_benchmark_statistics.py config1.cfg.1.log -p bechmark_results.pdf
```

But:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named moveit_benchmark_statistics.py below /opt/ros/groovy/share/moveit_ros_benchmarks
```

I've installed the newest version of moveit.
How can I make it work?

Thx in advance
viovio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59616/can%27t-find-moveit_benchmark_statistics.py/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks as if this script is not included in the `ros-groovy-moveit-ros-benchmarks` debian package.  I'm not sure if this was deliberate, or is just an oversight.  You should contact the package maintainers (see the [package.xml](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/groovy-devel/benchmarks/package.xml)) for more clarification.

If you look at the package's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/groovy-devel/benchmarks/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt), you can see that the other package executables are added to the install() script, but not `moveit_benchmark_statistics.py`.

You could always try to grab that python script directly from the [source repository](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/groovy-devel/benchmarks/benchmarks/scripts/moveit_benchmark_statistics.py) and run it independently from the package itself.  Depending on how the script is set up, that may work.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1